# How can I use arptables to limit the number of outgoing ARP requests a second?

Tags: linux, shell-script, limit, arp, cisco

**End goal:** Make a script that will limit the number of outgoing ARP requests in a second using `arptables`.

This is to have the ability to not trip the ARP-limiting feature on Cisco devices.

I want to make it in a shell-script, but if anyone has any thoughts or ideas, I am more than happy to listen.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `ebt_limit`?

```
ebtables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p ARP --limit 100/second -j ACCEPT
ebtables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p ARP -j DROP
```

Inspiration: http://blog.cyberlynx.eu/2015/limit-arp-flood-from-bridged-vms/